# Tornado unittesting with tornado.options

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I am trying to write unit tests for a Tornado web app and I have trouble on how to properly test code that uses the options module. I define several options and access them in multiple places in the application, hence, I want to test different option combinations in the unit test.

A very simple example that contains everything would be:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import define, options
import tornado.ioloop


def define_options():
    define('myoption', type=str, default='MyValue')


class ExampleHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write({
            'myoption': options.myoption
        })


def make_app():
    ROUTES = [
        (r'/', ExampleHandler)
    ]
    return tornado.web.Application(ROUTES)


def run():
    define_options()
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

The big issue seems to be that the options are persisted over all tests that are being run and I don't see where I should call `define_options` and how to change single test parameters without potentially affecting all other tests. Take the following example of a test code:

```
import tornado.testing
from demo import define_options, make_app

class Test1(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        define_options()
        super().setUp()

    def get_app(self):
        return make_app()

    def test1(self):
        response = self.fetch('/')
        print(response)
```

This works fine, but as soon as I add a second test method:

```
def test2(self):
    response = self.fetch('/')
    print(response)
```

I will get an error like this:

```
File "/Users/jan/Documents/demo/demo/demo.py", line 7, in define_options
    define('myoption', type=str, default='MyValue')
  File "/Users/jan/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/options.py", line 558, in define
    callback=callback)
  File "/Users/jan/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/options.py", line 228, in define
    (name, self._options[name].file_name))
tornado.options.Error: Option 'myoption' already defined in /Users/jan/Documents/demo/demo/demo.py
```

I can move the `define_options` to `setUpClass` but then I will see the same problem once I add a second test class. Hence, I am wondering if anyone has run into that issue and what solution I could use to run these tests. Not only where to put `define_options` so it is only run once, but also how I could define a different set of options (starting from the defaults given in `define_options`) for different tests without tests affecting each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tornado.options` can be used in two ways:

- **Using global singletons.** In this mode, you call `tornado.options.define` *at import time*, access the results via `tornado.options.options`, and parse the command line (or config file) with top-level functions in the `tornado.options` module. In this example, you'd remove your `define_options()` function and just define all your options at top level.
- **Using distinct `tornado.options.OptionParser` objects.** In this mode, you'd create an `OptionParser()` object in your `define_options()` function, call its `define()` and parse methods instead of the functions in the `options` module`, and return it so that other code accesses the values through this object instead of`tornado.options.options`.

Note that the global singleton style is the way that the `tornado.options` module was originally designed and is intended to be used (it draws inspiration from Google's C++ `gflags` package). One thing that can be a bit tricky in this style is to temporarily change a flag's value for a test. The `unittest.mock` package has a little trouble with the magic objects used in `tornado.options`, so you must use a helper method, [`mockable()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/options.html#tornado.options.OptionParser.mockable).